# Modifying a certain element in a Array List

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, element

How can I reference the x-position of the first ball and use that on the second ball?

```
private List<Ball> createBalls() {
    List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>();

    balls.add(new Ball(Color.BLUE, 600, 400, 20, rInt(-15,15), rInt(-15,15)));
    balls.add(new Ball(Color.RED, ball(1).get position 1, 500, 13, rInt(-15,15), rInt(-15,15)));
    balls.add(new Ball(Color.GREEN, 320, 340, 20, rInt(-15,15), rInt(-15,15)));
    balls.add(new Ball(Color.YELLOW, 50, 400, 50, rInt(-15,15), rInt(-15,15)));
    balls.add(new Ball(Color.orange, 600, 300, 15, rInt(-15,15), rInt(-15,15)));
    balls.add(new Ball(Color.CYAN, 320, 340, 10, rInt(-15,15), rInt(-15,15)));
    balls.add(new Ball(Color.GRAY, 50, 400, 60, rInt(-15,15), rInt(-15,15)));
    balls.add(new Ball(Color.magenta, 320, 340, 25, rInt(-15,15), rInt(-15,15)));
    balls.add(new Ball(Color.white, 50, 400, 40, rInt(-15,15), rInt(-15,15)));
    balls.add(new Ball(Color.YELLOW, 800, 200, 500, rInt(-15,15), rInt(-15,15)));

    return balls;
}
```

In my ball class I have

```
    public double getPositionX() {
        return positionX;
    }

    public void setPositionX(double positionX) {
        this.positionX = positionX;
    }
```

Comment: "Position value of the X position value for the next element position value?" What?

Comment: I think you are looking for a way to increment the `x` position adding onto previous balls `x` position. For that you need to store the previous ball to variable `Ball prev = new Ball(Color.BLUE, 600, 400, 20, rInt(-15,15), rInt(-15,15))` then in second do something like `prev.getPositionX()` assuming you have `getPositionX()` in Ball class that returns its `X position`.

Comment: Your question is not clear reorganize it.

Comment: position value of the position value for the next position value? pls clarify what do you mean.

Comment: I am clarifying the quetion now thanks

Comment: @JulianJacobs You want X position of 1st ball only for second ball or for every other ball objects?

Comment: I want all eventually but at the moment just for the 2nd ball

Comment: You can use `balls.get(0).getPositionX()`.

Comment: yea I modified my code and I think it work but it won't let me run the code it tells me

Comment: at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: It doesn't show any errors in code only when I try running

Comment: Please add the full stack to your question.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at GameModel.createBalls(GameModel.java:21)
 at GameModel.<init>(GameModel.java:13)
 at CollisionGame.<init>(CollisionGame.java:18)
 at CollisionGame$1.run(CollisionGame.java:9)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at

Comment: java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread

Comment: Last 3 section combined is the full error

Comment: @JulianJacobs Show the updated code.

Comment: I already edited it in this question. It is in the original question

Comment: @JulianJacobs So this is how you are getting the first ball's x position `balls.get(1).getPositionX()`? Add that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand but to get a value of X (assuming there is a Ball.getX().
then:  `balls.get(1).getX();`

"for the next element position value?"

You can't get the "next element" before you create it.  So after you create the Balls loop though the list and apply the "get next X value" logic.

If you show more code and explain what you are trying to do a little more clearly it would help.

Comment: So I changed it and I think it works now but it won't let me run and I have no errors in code

Comment: at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: That stack trace you provided doesn't help, normally it would have line numbers or at least show one of your classes in the trace.  What is the Exception?

Comment: @Alzoid Its `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Check the comments on question. And the first ball should be accessed by index 0 not 1.